# how to insert separate lines ( elements ) in parameter

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have the following csv file

```
more file.csv

1,yes,yes,customer1,1,2,3,4
2,no,yes,customer5,34,56,33,2
3,yes,yes,customer11
4,no,no,customer14
5,yes,no,customer15
6,yes,yes,customer21
7,no,yes,customer34
8,no,yes,customer89
```

The following (awk) line was written in order to manipulate and take line from the csv and put each element  (line)  in to the parameter - LINES

```
  declare LINES=`  awk -F, 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} $2=="yes"  {printf "\"Line number %d customer %s\"\n", $1, $4}' file.csv `
```

.

```
 echo $LINES

"Line number 1 customer customer1" "Line number 3 customer customer11" "Line number 5 customer customer15" "Line number 6 customer 21”
```

but when I want to print the number of elemnt in parameter **LINES** I get **1** ??

```
echo ${#LINES[*]} 
1
```

While actually I need to get **4** elements ( lines )

Please advice how to fix the awk line in order to get 4 elements?

remark:

please see this example , when I edit manual the LINES , the elements should be 4

```
     declare LINES=(  "Line number 1 customer customer1" "Line number 3 customer customer11" "Line number 5 customer customer15" "Line number 6 customer 21” )


echo ${#LINES[*]}

4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
a=$(awk -F, 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} $2=="yes"  {printf  "Line number %d customer %s;", $1, $4}' file.csv)    
IFS=';' read -a LINES <<< "${a}"
```

Comment: It's not useful to complicate the solution with an extra variable and a semi-colon as the line terminator and a separate read command. Simply set IFS to a newline and populate LINES using array delimiters and you're done, see the solution I just posted.

Answer (score 4):

The `awk` output isn't being stored in an array. You’d need `declare -a LINES=($(...))` to do that. But even then, bash splits array elements on any whitespace, not only newlines.  And if you were to wrap the process substitution in quotes like `LINES=("$(...)")` you would only have a single element containing the entire output from the command.

You could do the necessary text manipulation with a `read` loop to preserve the number of elements that contain whitespace.

```
declare -a lines
while IFS=, read -r line_number answer _ customer _; do
    if [[ $answer == @(yes|YES) ]]; then
        lines+=("Line number $line_number customer $customer")
    fi
done < file.csv
```

As noted in the comments, depending on the `bash` version, usage of `@(...)` inside `[[ ... ]]` may require `shopt -s extglob`.

Alternatively, the `if` could be replaced with a `case`:

```
case $answer in
    yes|YES)
        LINES+=("Line number $line_number customer $customer")
        ;;          
esac
```

Comment: A minor note: some older versions of `bash` may need `shopt -s extglob` to support the `@(yes|YES)` pattern. I always forget which version enables that option inside `[[ ... ]]` by default.

Comment: I have a problem about the csv file , csv files could have more then four fields  for example line in csv could be 12 fields as ( 1,yes,yes,customer1 ,a,b,c,d,e,f,r )

Comment: @maihabunash That's an easy fix.  You can just add another junk `read` variable named `_` to take care of the trailing fields.  I've added the extra `_` in my most recent edit.

Comment: @maihabunash the rest of the fields are catched by `_` in the `read -r line_number answer _ customer _` block. To manage this info, you can name them to something like `read -r line_number answer _ customer myfield _`, etc. Otherwise they get stored in `_` with no effect.

Comment: or you can read the entire line in to an array and cherry pick the fields you want.

Comment: I notice on another problem when I run the code twice or more then $lines remember the previos number and add the new one , so how to erasde the $line in order to get each time only the relevant lines?

Comment: please run your code twice or more and you see that -:) , or maybe before declare - how to erase the $lines ???

Comment: @maihabunash Yes, that's probably happening because you're running the code in a prompt and not resetting the `lines` array to be empty every time you run the loop.  Am I right? Otherwise, you'll just keep appending the array with duplicate entries.  Try putting the code in a script.  It should give you the same output every time.  Alternatively, instead of `declare -a lines`, try using `lines=()`.

Comment: @jaypal You certainly could!

Comment: +1 for explaining the root problem the OP was having, populating LINES as a scalar instead of an array.

Answer (score 3):

As @JohnB mentioned, you are populating LINES as a scalar variable, not an array. Try this:

```
$ IFS=$'\n' LINES=( $(awk 'BEGIN{for(i=1;i<=3;i++) printf "\"Line number %d\"\n", i}') )

$ echo ${#LINES[*]}
3

$ echo "${LINES[0]}"
"Line number 1"

$ echo "${LINES[1]}"
"Line number 2"

$ echo "${LINES[2]}"
"Line number 3"
```

and tweak to suit your real input/output which would probably result in:

```
IFS=$'\n' LINES=( $(awk -F, 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} $2=="yes"{printf "\"Line number %d customer %s\"\n", $1, $4}' file.csv) )
```

Comment: @maihabunash if you agree that this is the correct answer, you should click on the check mark next to it to let others know who're looking this up in future.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using bash, you can just use the `mapfile` builtin:

```
$ mapfile -t LINES < \
    <(awk -F, 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} 
    $2=="yes"  {printf "\"Line number %d customer %s\"\n", $1, $4}' file.csv)
$ echo "${#LINES[*]}"
4
$ echo "${LINES[@]}"
"Line number 1 customer customer1" "Line number 3 customer customer11" "Line number 5 customer customer15" "Line number 6 customer customer21"
```